# Как запустить messagebox без окна Tk

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть программа. Она открывает сайт если я нажимаю Yes, а если No messagebox закрывается. Но есть проблема вместе с messagebox появляется Tk окно я не хочу, чтобы оно появлялось. 
Как это сделать?

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from webbrowser import open

ans = messagebox.askyesno(message="открыть сайт")
if ans == True:
    open('https://google.com')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Кто ищет... тот находит*

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser


window = Tk()
window.withdraw()# Спрятать окно

ans = messagebox.askyesno(message="открыть сайт")
if ans == True:
    webbrowser.open('https://google.com')
```